# If Pricipal Ideal generated by $a\in R$ then Subring

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $a\in R$. Prove that principal ideal $aR\equiv \{ ar:r\in R \}$ is a subring

---

*Closed add.*

Let $ar_1,\in aR$ and $ ar_2 \in aR$ so 
$$\begin{aligned} ar_1+ar_2=a(r_1+r_2) && \text{by left distribution prop of rings } \end{aligned} $$

*Closed mult* 
$$\begin{aligned}ar_1*ar_2=a(r_1 a r_2)&& \text{} \end{aligned} $$ 
Since $r_1,a,r_2 \in R$ and mult closed under $R$:  $r_1ar_2 \in R$. So $ar_1*ar_2 \in aR$

$\exists 0_r \in a R$ since $0_r*a=0_r$

*Additive inverse*
 since $\forall r\in R$,$\exists -r \in R:r+(-r)=0_R $ so, $a(-r) \in R$. So, $$\forall ar \in R, \exists a (-r) \in aR:ar+a(-r)=a(r-r)=a*0_R=0_R$$

---

Did I do something wrong?? also, I welcome any other ways of showing it.

Comment: found similar show Ideal is a subring but dosent specify Principal http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/500212/show-that-ideal-is-a-subring

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you did is correct. However, an ideal (principal or not) is a subring only if you don't require your rings to have a multiplicative identity. If you do, then a proper ideal is never a subring.

Comment: what is "your rings" mean? I am thinking the subring if it has $1_R$ then it is equiv to the super ring where it came from right

Comment: I meant that it depends on your definition of ring. If in the definition you used you require the existence of a multiplicative inverse, then an ideal is not a subring. Otherwise it's correct.

Comment: But a ring doesn't require multiplicative identity. That is a ring with unity.

Comment: @ZelosMalum Again, it depends on the definition you use! And to be honest, it is much more usual to define a ring to have a multiplicative identity. That's why we invented the term rng.

Comment: I'd say it's a bad definition then on the basis that it excludes lots of things that are fine enough. While many rings have a unity in it, many doesn't, infinitely many in fact :P We might prefer them but that is no reason to be so discriminatory!

Comment: That's true. On the other hand, when you assume an identity, you can use the general framework of monoids in monoidal categories. Every defintion has its good sides and its bad sides.